# Problems adding angular material in stackblitz

Tags: angular-material, stackblitz

I have this sample: https://stackblitz.com/edit/partehoras?file=src/styles.css

Where I have installed angular material

[image]

I have created this material.module where I export all the modules needed

[image]

Then I import this module in app.module

[image]

In styles.scss i have imported one

```
@import '@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css';
```

But when I try this in my template

```
<mat-card>
......
<mat-card>
```

I get this error

[image]

Any idea, please?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ListadoEmpleadosComponent is missing from the list of declarations in app module and you also need to import HttpClientModule

```js
declarations: [ AppComponent, ListadoEmpleadosComponent ]
```